# Return Excel object type in selection

Tags: excel, office-js

In VBA, if I use `TypeName(Selection)`, I can see what object type is currently selected: I get `Range`, `Shape`, `ChartArea`, etc.

In JS, as far as i know, there is no `Selection` object so I can't validate if an user has made a proper selection in the worksheet. Currently, I just stick with a generic error handler that will fail if the user doesn't select a range when my script runs `workbook.getSelectedRange()`.

How can I detect what type is currently selected in the worksheet?

---

Edit: this is the code I'm using.

```
function btnApply_Click() {
    Excel.run(function (context) {

        var rangeSelection;

        return context.sync()
        .then(function () {
            rangeSelection = context.workbook.getSelectedRange();
            rangeSelection.load("values");
            return context.sync().catch(function (error) {
                throw new u.error.exclamation("The selection must be a cell.");
            });
        })
        .then(function () {
            var values = rangeSelection.values;
            convertSelection(values);
            rangeSelection.values = values;

            return context.sync();
        })
    })
    .catch(function (error) { u.error.show(error); });
}
```

Comment: Felipe, under what conditions do you not have a Range selection?  In my experience, I thought getSelectedRange always returns an object and never throws (and if you have something like a chart selected, or simply returns the last range).  Is that not the case?  (Note that I'm on vacation, so replies might be delayed.  But I do want to make sure we don't have a bug here)

Comment: `getSelectedRange` throws an error if my current selection is a `ChartObject`, a `Shape`, a `Picture`, an ActiveX Object or an embeded Office Addins `Rectangle` object to name a few. It is also important to notice that it also throws an error if a range selection has more than one area.

Comment: OK, thanks for reporting this (and apologies for the delay in responding, I was on vacation).  Would you mind opening a bug on https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/, so that we can look into this, and so that you can keep updated on the status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a callback parameter to the `getSelectedDataAsync` method. Office will pass an `AsyncResult` object to this callback. Inside the callback, the `AsyncResult.value.type` is the type of the object.

Comment: Thanks. I don't use any of these methods. I recall seeing them when Office Addins shipped to Excel 2013. With the version I'm using right now, where would I put these parameters? I edited my question and pasted the code I'm using.

Comment: @Felipe. I understand that you are not currently using getSelectedDataAsync. My answer is saying that you should. Using this method in the way I described is the answer to your question: "How can I detect what type is currently selected in the worksheet?"

Comment: Could you share a code snippet that shows how to determine what chart element is selected, or which chart is the active chart?

Comment: @JonPeltier That's really a different question. Can I ask you to create a new StackOverflow question? Thanks!

Comment: Rick, I was actually looking for examples that will help me understand what getSelectedDataAsync does. Somehow I led myself to believe it could tell me what objects (not just range of cells) is selected. I don't really understand the documentation and wanted to see some Excel-based samples.

Comment: Rick, I did ask [Identify Active Chart and Selected Chart Element in Office-JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49226837/identify-active-chart-and-selected-chart-element-in-office-js/), which you've already answered.