# Identify Active Chart and Selected Chart Element in Office-JS

Tags: excel, charts, office-js

I cobbled together some JavaScript to label the last point of each series in a chart (see below). This is a simplified version of a much-used function in a VBA add-in.

I used `let mychart = mysheet.charts.getItemAt(0);` to specify that the code should run on the first chart object on the worksheet. It would be more useful to run the code on the chart selected by the user.

1. How do I identify which chart the user has selected (`ActiveChart` in VBA-speak)?

Similarly I used `for (var iseries = 0; iseries < nseries; iseries++)` to run the code on all series in the chart. It would be more useful to run the code on the specific series selected by the user.

2. How do I identify which series in the chart has been selected by the user (related to `TypeName(Selection)` in VBA)?

Here is my Office-JS code:

```
    $("#run").click(() => tryCatch(labelLastPoint));
    //$("#label-last-point").click(labelLastPoint);
    async function labelLastPoint() {
        await Excel.run(async (context) => {
            let mysheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
            let mychart = mysheet.charts.getItemAt(0);

            let seriescollection = mychart.series;
            seriescollection.load("count");
            await context.sync();
            console.log("Number of Series: " + seriescollection.count);
            let nseries = seriescollection.count;

            for (var iseries = 0; iseries < nseries; iseries++) {
                console.log("- Series Number " + iseries);
                let myseries = seriescollection.getItemAt(iseries);
                let pointcollection = myseries.points;
                pointcollection.load("count");
                await context.sync();
                let npoints = myseries.points.count;
                let mypoint = myseries.points.getItemAt(npoints - 1);
                mypoint.hasDataLabel = true;
                mypoint.dataLabel.showSeriesName = true;
                mypoint.dataLabel.showValue = false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Jon, I don't know if it helps, but in this example ActiveChart is a member of Workbook: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/20965245/JavaScript-and-Excel-Chart-Nightmare.html

Comment: Thanks, Doug. That is very old JavaScript (2004), I'm guessing from the VB6 generation, and I think it's just running COM from JavaScript. It is distinct from the new Office-JS APIs which Microsoft is currently developing.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it you're looking for API methods that might be called "getSelectedChart" and "getSelectedSeries". I'm afraid that there are no APIs in Office JS that do that. But it is a good idea. Please suggest that at [Office Developer User Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

There is a getSelectedDataAsync method in the Shared Office JS APIs, but it does not support charts or series.

In the meantime, would it be possible in your scenario to have a drop down in the task pane, in which the user can specify, by title, the chart/series that is of interest?

Comment: Thanks, Rick. I've actually spoken with some Microsoft people over the past week at the MVP Summit and made these same suggestions. I'd actually like one called "getSelection", which is more general, and means we won't need a new function for every chart element (like getSelectedAxis, getSelectedDataLabel, getSelectedLegendEntry, etc.). This can be modeled after VBA's Selection object, which I use extensively to determine what the user has selected and therefore what my code will do..

Comment: Rick - I've thought of using some kind of listbox or dropdown to let the user indicate which particular element should be acted on, and in fact, I looped through all series in the chart to help my proof of concept. But much more general and useful and transparent to the user would be for the code to know what's selected, and act accordingly.